# How to hide/toggle legends based on addLayerControl() in Leaflet for R

Tags: r, leaflet, legend

I'm wondering how to hide/toggle legends based on `addLayerControl()` in Leaflet for R? When option layer a is toggled, then the data of option layer b is not shown by `addPolygons()` because I can use `group`. However, the `addLegend()` option doesn't have the `group` functionality so I'm not able to hide the legend of group layer b (blue) when I selected group layer a (red):

[image]

[source](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214773/how-to-hide-toggle-legends-with-layer-controls-in-leaflet-for-r)

Do you have any idea how to do this?

Regards,

Joris

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case anyone is looking at this in the future, there's a new viable method.

If you're using the development/Github version of the `leaflet` package, `addLegend()` now supports the `group` and `layerId` arguments.

(Run the command `devtools::install_github('rstudio/leaflet')` to install)

Even the latest CRAN version (1.1.0) supports `layerID`.

Assuming you go with the development version, the following code should work:

```r
leaflet() %>%
    #Polygon Layers
    addPolygons(data = exampleDataOne, group = "Group A") %>%
    addPolygons(data = exampleDataTwo, group = "Group B") %>%

    #Legend Layers
    addLegend(values = exampleValuesOne, group = "Group A", 
              position = "bottomright") %>%
    addLegend(values = exampleValuesTwo, group = "Group B",
              position = "bottomright") %>%

    #Layers Control
    addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c("Group A","Group B"),
              options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE))
```

This should have the desired effect of only displaying a legend when the corresponding layer is active.

One potential issue is that by default, all `leaflet` layers are active. If you have overlapping polygons, this can lead to a less visually appealing map. And, if you have multiple legends, this will also be an issue.

What you can do is use the `hideGroup()` function.

If you wanted to have only `Group A` from the above example active at start, you could add

`%>% hideGroup("Group B")`

to the end of the code block above.

Comment: Nice solution, however it's important to note that it (seems) doesn't work with `overlayGroups` option in `addLayersControl`

Comment: While this explanation is very clear and concise, it didn't work for me with markers. When I assign the same group name to the `addCircles()` and `addLegend()` layers, say `Group A`, then the `%>% hideGroup("Group A")` operations only hides the markers, it doesn't make the legend go away. I am puzzled.

Answer (score 4):

This code worked for me:

```
observeEvent(input$mymap_groups,{
    mymap <- leafletProxy("mymap", data = SalesMap)
    mymap %>% clearControls()
    if (input$mymap_groups == '1') {
      mymap %>% addLegend(position="bottomright", pal=pal1, values=SalesMap$SALES, title="a")
    }
    else if (input$mymap_groups == '2') {
      mymap %>% addLegend(position="bottomright", pal=pal2, values=SalesMap$Bonnen, title="b")
    }
  })
```

You can use input$mymap_groups to identify what kind of group is selected.In the observeEvent() you can use an if/else statement to create a legend based on a group.

Comment: For people looking at this answer: this has the advantage of keeping the layers as baseGroups() (radio buttons) BUT only when leaflet is used in shiny.